# HJS-480-0-24 Power Supply begins smelling like burning plastic after 30 seconds of running

Tags: power-supply, troubleshooting

I recently purchased a HJS-480-0-24 power supply off Banggood and I tested it out by running a 150 watt heater. After 30 seconds the power supply began to smell like burning plastic, so I immediately turned it off.

According to the seller, the cooling fan does not turn on until the device is at 40°C. I tested the fan and it works if I power it externally, but I havent seen it turn on yet by its self (which makes sense as the power supply probably isnt reaching 40°C in 30 seconds).

I opened it up and not a single component looks to be damaged. As best as I could tell, either the big capacitors or the inductors seemed to be the smelly culprits, but again they showed no sign of damage or swelling. The fuse is intact and the supply still fully works, but I'm just paranoid that something will catch fire or explode if I run it for more than 30 seconds. Is this normal for a new power supply to smell bad during the first while of use? What should my next steps be here?

Comment: Things smelling bad when they first turn on and volatile cleaning agents get forced off by the heat isn't too uncommon, though it's not super common either. Since this is an unknown device from an unknown source (as all components on banggood, aliexpress, ebay, and amazon should be treated as), I can't say one way or the other whether it's a problem. Keep a fire extinguisher handy.

Comment: Or buy from respected manufacturers. Not advertising against banggood, ebay, etc, they're cheap, but safety and quality, etc have a price.

Comment: > QA problems  > banggood

Comment: I think the answer is "all of the above". Generally, you get what you pay for.  Inexpensive manufacturing processes possibly didn't clean adequately the circuit board assembly (not to U.S. standards, anyway) and so as the components heat up you're smelling flux residues, adhesives/resins, and other volatile organic compounds (VOC) as they evaporate off the (phenolic?) circuit board and its components. FWIW, laminated phenolic paper circuit boards can/do emit a very distinctive odor when heated (Google "old electronics smell" or "old amplifier smell").

Comment: And who knows what degree of burn-in testing these companies use to ensure quality and reliability in their products. Note that if that power supply fails catastrophically and burns down your home, you (or your insurance company) can't realistically sue the Chinese manufacturer. OTOH, if you live in the US and a US-made product, or US-based firm sells a product that burns your house down, you can definitely sue the manufacturer, or the US-based company who sells the product, or both in the hope of financial or other remedial compensation (see also "product liability laws").